# How can I create new project in BigQuery and create new dataset using public dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics

I am new to BigQuery and found it difficult to create new project and create new dataset inside the new project. I want to use public dataset to create the dataset in my new project

First up, I tried to create new dataset in main project I am using in the BigQuery console and its working normal when I upload data from local drive. But; I got bogged down trying to use public dataset

Comment: Welcome to the community!!! ... Have a read at the following:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data

Unfortunately, there isn't much in your post we can use to assist.  Consider your post from the perspective of a new reader ... add as much detail as needed.   For example "I got bogged down trying to use public dataset" .... what did you try?  What happened?  What were the exact commands you used?  What were the exact results?  What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Its a very broad question you are asking, I would recommend this link from optimize smart as they are very good at covering the basics.
https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-access-bigquery-public-data-sets/

Answer (score 0):

Public dataset or not you can copy tables in the same way and you
have three ways to achieve this:

1. BigQuery Interface:
   Select the table and hit **copy** in upper menu, in the left panel insert your project, dataset and table name, in this step you can create a new dataset too.
2. BQ Command-line:
   Use the command `bq cp myDataset.myTable myDataset.myTableCopy`, for more information access this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_cp)

> Remember: [Cloud Shell](https://shell.cloud.google.com) already has cli tools installed, enjoy
> it.

3. Using Clint libraries:
   Use your preferred programming language to copy the table. Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-copy-table).